# Return string from HttpRequest

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-async

In Dart I can do:

```
await HttpRequest.getString(path)
```

and this will return a string.

I want to create a method that will do the same, but like this:

```dart
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request
    ..open('Get',getPath)
    ..setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
    ..send('');
...
return responseString;
```

I can do it using events and futures, but I would like to understand how to do it with async & await specifically.

Edit:
This is for the dart:html HttpRequest for browser.

Comment: Want to do it where? In JavaScript on a browser? Or in Dart?

Comment: Ah, good point. Thought it was obviopus using HttpRequest. But in browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't tried but I guess this is what you're looking for

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
 print(await getString());
}

Future<String> getString() async {
  String getPath = 'https://dartpad.dartlang.org/';
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  request
    ..open('Get',getPath)
    ..setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
    ..send('');

  // request.onReadyStateChange.listen(print);
  await request.onLoadEnd.first;

  return request.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle! Thats the one, or at least it works and shows me steps I need for anything else.